# Get MovieClip in another frame

Tags: flash, movieclip, cs4

I'm in frame 1 of a movie, and I want to use getChildByName("mc_movieclip"); to get a reference to mc_movieclip. The problem is that mc_movieclip does not exist in frame 1 but only in frame 5. How can I get a reference to this MovieClip, even though it's in another frame?

Comment: Why do you want to access the MovieClip early.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to fix this is that you put a copy of `mc_movieclip` on frame 1 and make it hidden. `mc_movieclip.visible=false` will do the trick.

**Note:** if your mc has animation (in its timeline) then you have to restart that animation on frame 5 to get the same effect as before.